# Integral question calculus cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider a cylindrical antenna of radius $R$ and length $L$. Assume the intensity of the radiation field inside
the antenna is proportional to the square of distance from the cylindrical outer wall and proportional to
$sin^2
(2πz/λ)$, where the $z$ coordinate aligns with the cylinder axis and $λ$ is the wavelength of the radiation
(∼ 12cm for Wifi). Find the total energy inside the antenna as the integral of the intensity

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: My thoughts are that I=intensity = kD where D is distance from wall to some point inside the cylinder so this can be considered as the 'r' in polar. Other than that I dont know

Comment: The question says " the intensity of the radiation field inside the antenna is proportional to the square of distance from the cylindrical outer wall" so you might want to consider $I = k D^2$

Comment: Oh right, I meant $I=kD^2$ not $I=kD$ but i dont know where to go further from there i know $0<D<R$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$ but i dont really see how i can work out the integral of intensity using this